# Count the instance of a returned value from a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to count the instances of a returned value and display it in a new column.
Like this. All I have found is how to count the total number.

```
apple   1
apple   2
apple   3
pear    1
pear    2
grape   1
grape   2
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `row_number()`:

```
select val, row_number() over (partition by val order by val) as seqnum
from t;
```

Comment: One more question, how can I get a count of a value in the partition. This has 2 values 0 or 1, I need to count the 1's in each partition.